# in .state onExit call functions from several controllers in the view being exited

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

it would be handy to call save functions for several controllers in the view being exited. anyone have an example of how to call these? I've tried nested controllers with the top level defined in the state but there is no way to invoke functions in child controllers

Answer (score 1):

Have you had a look at `$stateChangeStart` event in the `ui-router`. You can attach even handler to this event in each controller to do custom logic processing

```
$scope.$on('$stateChangeStart', 
function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
    //Code to call before state change is complete.
})
```

See documentation here https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki